# Lambda expression oddity

Tags: c#, lambda, operator-precedence

Long story short. I have 2 lists which contain the same type (but are used for different things) and I want to know if EITHER list contains an item with a certain name.

My original code, which worked prefectly, was:

```
if (listA.Any(var => var.Name == strMatch) || listB.Any(var => var.Name == strMatch))
{
    //Do something
}
```

This code worked perfectly, whether the item was present in either or both lists.
Later on, I had several 'impossible' crashes -- Things which never could have happened.
I traced it back to that if statement NEVER returning true.

This stumped me for ages... I couldn't work out what was going wrong. Eventually I gave up and stuck brackets around the body of the lamda expressions like so...

```
if (listA.Any(var => (var.Name == strMatch)) || listB.Any(var => (var.Name == strMatch)))
{
    //Do something
}
```

After re-running my program, all the 'impossible' errors went away and it functioned normally. Removing the extra backets cause the errors to reappear.

I've never had this problem with lambda expressions before (especially where they work and THEN, after several runs working correctly break) and my other lambda expressions work correctly.

Example: The following code works 100% as expected (Assuming that there is a match in one of the lists)

```
Item item =
    ListA.FirstOrDefault(var => var.Name == strMatch) ??
    ListB.FirstOrDefault(var => var.Name == strMatch);
```

What's going on? Why is the compiler picky about **some** lamda expressions and not others? (Even when they are identical?) ???

**UPDATE :: System Details**
This was encountered with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (Professional), Windows Vista 32bit.

**UPDATE**
[Video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVROKeNGa-g), this has been test on other computers and is **NOT** reproducable. Makes me feel like my computer is doomed. Reinstallion of VS has no effect.

Please ignore any background cat noises, she only meows alot when she hears me recording something.

Comment: Is this the actual verbatim code that's behaving oddly?

Comment: If you can actually reproduce this, you should take more steps on your own machine to identify the problem, e.g. what differs in the bytecode when you add or remove the parentheses?

Comment: The code is verbatim, except that the names of the lists where changed to allow for easier reading out of context, and the actual type is called "Variable", not "Item".

Comment: @mquander surely you mean IL code, as few people read .net ByteCode?

Comment: What else do you do in your code? Are you multi-threading? Are you using unsafe code segments somewhere? I'd suspect corrupted data or code as the cause of this behaviour, rather than the compiler.

Comment: No unsafe code in the project, no multi-threading. Just using a default console application with no special references and only the default `using` s + `using System.IO;`

Answer (score 3):

Those extra parentheses do not change the meaning of those lambda expressions, nor how the compiler chooses to compile those two different blocks of code. Based on what you've provided, there appears to be no functional difference between your two choices and thus the problem is unrelated to the parentheticals.

**EDIT:**

So I created a quick class that does exactly what you stated, and the IL differs only in class names. I used `ildasm` and `windiff` to confirm this. Nor does it change with `/optimize-` or `/debug:full`.

```
  .method /*06000005*/ public hidebysig 
          instance bool  '<Main>b__3'(class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Tuple`2/*01000006*/<int32,string> var) cil managed
  // SIG: 20 01 02 15 12 19 02 08 0E
  {
    // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
    // Code size       22 (0x16)
    .maxstack  2
    .locals /*11000001*/ init ([0] bool CS$1$0000)
-   .line 29,29 : 69,92 ''
+   .line 29,29 : 67,88 ''
-   //000029:       if (listA.Any(var => (var.Item2 == strMatch)) || listB.Any(var => (var.Item2 == strMatch)))
+   //000029:       if (listA.Any(var => var.Item2 == strMatch) || listB.Any(var => var.Item2 == strMatch))
    IL_0000:  /* 03   |                  */ ldarg.1
    IL_0001:  /* 6F   | (0A)000005       */ callvirt   instance !1 class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Tuple`2/*01000006*/<int32,string>/*1B000001*/::get_Item2() /* 0A000005 */
    IL_0006:  /* 02   |                  */ ldarg.0
-   IL_0007:  /* 7B   | (04)000001       */ ldfld      string Parentheses/*02000002*//'<>c__DisplayClass6'/*02000003*/::strMatch /* 04000001 */
+   IL_0007:  /* 7B   | (04)000001       */ ldfld      string NoParentheses/*02000002*//'<>c__DisplayClass6'/*02000003*/::strMatch /* 04000001 */
    IL_000c:  /* 28   | (0A)000006       */ call       bool [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.String/*01000007*/::op_Equality(string, string) /* 0A000006 */
    IL_0011:  /* 0A   |                  */ stloc.0
    IL_0012:  /* 2B   | 00               */ br.s       IL_0014
```

**Nota bene:** there are two of these generated, one for each of the `listX.Any` calls. Both only differ in their comments. The generated IL is identical.

**EDIT 2:**

The output from `ildasm` for Visual Studio 2008 (csc 3.5.30729.4926) is also no different, so I'm really unable to say why in your instance of VS2k8 it dies besides perhaps the version of LINQ you have is bugged or the compiler on that machine has a bugged Expression generator, because I cannot replicate any difference.

Comment: That's what the question is about. There should be no difference

Comment: As an aside, you should probably choose a better variable name than `var`. While it is only a contextual keyword, something like `item` or `xx`, et al, is probably a better choice.

Comment: James I'm saying there **is** no difference. The difference lies elsewhere if that is truly your code.

Comment: The point of the question is that there __is__ no difference, the compiler is picky to __those__ parentheses only, and not in other lambda expressions. I know there's no difference which is what confuses me

Comment: I'm saying the generated code does not differ, hence it cannot be picky to those parentheses. If there is no change in what is executed in those lines, the problem exists somewhere else. Likely you're seeing a Heisenbug that has manifest itself near those lines of code.

Comment: James, your computer ain't magic.  The only effect that your source code has on your running program is through the compiled executable.  If it compiles to the same thing, there is no difference, and the compiler is not "picky."

Comment: I'll be back in the morning, will upload some "evidence" of my compiler being picky.

Comment: Check the video and tell me it's not picky. Spent hours getting the darn software to record but what you see there is uneditted (Actually I lie, I trimmed the first 3seconds where you see me clicking the record button)